# What's the meaning of the definition "suggesting physical pleasure"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

**Sensual mouth**

Dictionary meaning of sensual—suggesting physical pleasure, so what's the meaning of **suggest** here?what's the meaning of "suggesting physical pleasure"??

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking the meaning of "sensual mouth", or "suggesting physical pleasure"? Also, please [edit] your question to link the source

Comment: @gotube I want to know the meaning of definition?? (Especially 'suggesting' )

Comment: Your title and the body of your question ask two different things. Please fix this and add a link to your source.

Comment: @gotube ok, done.

Comment: If thing A suggests thing B, it makes you think of thing B. See 'suggest' in a good dictionary, e.g. Cambridge: suggest verb [T] (PRODUCE AN IDEA) formal _to produce an idea in the mind_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OP's context, ***suggesting*** is the same as ***implying, hinting at, involving*** - or more directly, simply ***meaning***.

That's to say, when the word ***sensual*** is applied to ***mouth***, it makes us think of the mouth as something *sexy* (for *kissing*), rather than the place where food goes in, or where speech comes out.

Comment: It's only (for kissing ), one can think of it(mouth) in other sexual ways.

Comment: The meaning of "sensual" is not exclusively sexual, as this answer implies.

Comment: @BadZen: I'm sure the OP is quite capable of understanding the possible difference between ***sensual*** and ***sexy*** - which is pretty clearly spelled out by the first paragraph of Jay's answer anyway. But that's not what's being asked about, is it? So really, your comment is just pointlessly distracting "noise".

Comment: And yet Sam's comment immediately above seems to imply otherwise.   In any case, "when the word sensual is applied to mouth, it makes us think of the mouth as something sexy (for kissing), rather than the place where food goes in, or where speech comes out" is like a personal problem or opinion and not a universal language principle.

Answer (score 1):

"Sensual" means pleasing to the senses. It is often used in connection with sex, so often that now any other meaning is likely to be taken as a double entendre.

So if you say, "she had a sensual mouth", you mean that her mouth makes you think of sex or you can imagine her using her mouth in some sexual way.

Comment: I can think of various UK TV ads for chocolate products that were 'sensual', including a very famous one for Cadbury's Flake, which involved a young female model slowly unwrapping and eating one while taking a bath, and being so distracted she doesn't notice the water is overflowing. The product is a cylinder or rod made of flaky chocolate.

Comment: The question asks what ***suggesting*** means in the context of the dictionary definition. It doesn't ask the meaning of ***sensual***.